# AWS SNS:How to send notifications to multiple arns use same SNS topic

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

As my question says ,i would like to send notifications to multiple ARN"s using a 
single SNS topic..please let know if it is possible
i tried in amazon console  able to select only one ARN at a time for a topic in the dropdownlist of ARN"s

i tried configuring in cloud formation template as well.please help!!

Comment: What kind of ARN do you want to send to multiple of?  An SNS topic has one and only one ARN. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i want to send notifications to multiple arn:aws:sns (SNS ARN)..what im trying to accomplish is prod team has difeerent SNS ARN and we application team has different one...so i need notifications to be sent to both the teams...and the topic is attached to a cloudwatch alarm

Comment: How about sending the notifcation to a single sns topic and registering two suscriptions (prod and app teams) for that topic?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to send a single message to multiple SNS topics at the same time.

A single SNS message can only be sent to one SNS topic.

However, you could setup a third SNS topic which is designed for messages that go to multiple topics.

For example, TopicC could be designed to forward to TopicA and TopicB. Doing this, you would subscribe a Lambda function to TopicC, and in that Lambda function, forward the message to TopicA and TopicB.

Comment: i have only one topic but need to send the notifications to multiple SNS Arn"s not multiple SNS topics...please see my message in the question

Comment: If not a topic ARN, what kind of SNS ARN are you trying to send to? Please supply a sample ARN.

Answer (score 0):

Official documentation, "When a topic is created, Amazon SNS will assign a unique ARN (Amazon Resource Name) to the topic, ..." https://aws.amazon.com/sns/faqs/